# Softaculous com erro de de conexão com MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou trabalhando em um servidor de hospedagem com o `centos-webpanel` e com um servidor `MySQL` remoto. O `centos-webpanel` já está funcionando normalmente com o MySQL remoto, ele cria os bancos e usuários o `phpmyadmin` também está OK. Porem não consigo instalar nada que utilize o `MySQL` pelo `Softaculous`, pois ele apresenta o erro a baixo

> The following errors were found :
>
> The MySQL Connection could not be established.

Percebi que o `Softaculous` chega a criar o usuário mas como `localhost` no servidor remoto e também nota se existir algum banco com o mesmo nome, sendo assim não é possível ele conectar no server remoto com essa permissão.
Percebi que o `Softaculous` chega a criar o usuário mas como `localhost` no servidor remoto e também nota se existir algum banco com o mesmo nome, sendo assim não é possível ele conectar no server remoto com essa permissão.

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver esse erro atualizando o cpanel

```
/scripts/upcp --force
```